# Openlayers 3 map, how refresh without having focus

Tags: javascript, focus, openlayers

I have two similar problems with an Openlayers 3 map. They both pertain to making the map refresh/redraw when it doesn't have focus; i.e. when the mouse is not over it.

1)  I show an outline of a country when the mouse is over it, but it becomes transparent when the mouse moves off.  However, if the country is at the edge of the map view and I move the mouse off that edge of the map, the country stays outlined, because the map never sees the mouse over another area outside the country.

2)  When I click on a country, it becomes permanently highlighted (i.e. a layer becomes visible).  I have a button off the map that when clicked resets all the layers to transparent.  When I click the button, nothing happens until I move the mouse back over the map, at which point the change becomes apparent and the layers disappear.

Is there a way to force the map to update when the mouse is not over it?

I have tried several options:  `map.redraw()`, `layer.redraw()`, `source.refresh()`, `map.refresh()`, `layer.refresh()`, `source.refresh()`, `document.getElementById("map").focus()` and anything else I can find suggested to force a map to refresh, but none of them work until the mouse is moved over the map.

Comment: Have you tried `map.render()` or `map.renderSync()` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both of those, still no effect until I mouse over the map again.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify.  When the mouse is over a country, the style of the vector over that country changes darkness ( color goes from 0,0,0,0 to 0,0,0,.2).  It is the style that is not getting updated when the mouse is off the map.  I'm setting the style in code, but it is not changing on the map until the mouse comes back over the map.

Comment: Are you using a Select interaction?  If so which version of OpenLayers?

Comment: See my comment below.  This issue is closed.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, simple bug.  Failed to update the style directly, assuming another routine was handling it.